# How to calculate the virtual memory of a computer system?

Tags: memory, cpu, cpu-registers

For example the following details are given regarding a computer system,

```
word length             = 64 bits
internal registers      = 32 
address bus width       = 60 bits 
main memory             = 1GB
```

with the help of above details how to calculate system's virtual memory?

Also is that possible to calculate

- total memory occupied by the CPU internal register set
- maximum operands that can be handle

using above data?

Comment: Are you limited to a particular tool set or programming language?

Comment: @JECarterII this is a pen and paper question, no programming language involved.

Comment: @JECarterII yep just pen and paper. I just needed to know the methods.